# Android json parse

Tags: android, json

I am going to need a little help here as with a little bit of advice. I need an extra set of eyes to look my code and to see if there is an error with the Yahoo Answers JSON data that I have parsed. I think I have parsed the JSON data incorrectly and I just want somebody to look over it to make sure I have the right data parsed.

This is the data I am trying to parse from my web service:

```json
{
 "query": {
  "count": 1,
  "created": "2013-08-09T19:37:46Z",
  "lang": "en-US",
  "diagnostics": {
   "publiclyCallable": "true",
   "url": {
    "execution-start-time": "524",
    "execution-stop-time": "783",
    "execution-time": "259",
    "proxy": "DEFAULT",
    "content": "http://answers.yahooapis.com/AnswersService/V1/getQuestion?question_id=20100207231859AAZVura"
   },
   "user-time": "783",
   "service-time": "259",
   "build-version": "38788"
  },
  "results": {
   "Question": {
    "id": "20100207231859AAZVura",
    "type": "Answered",
    "Subject": "What gives some humans the idea that you cannot prove a negative?",
    "Content": "Seriously, humans, what is this nonsense?  For one thing, the statement 'You cannot prove a negative' is itself phrased negatively.  So if it's true, how could you possibly know?\n\nBut more to the point, a negative claim can be disproved in precisely the same ways as a positive claim.  Let's take something clearly false as an example, yes?  So, square circles.  If I say that there is a shape that is both a square and a circle, you can disprove my claim (that is, you can prove the negative claim that there is no such shape) by demonstrating that the property of being square contradicts the property of being circular.  Simple, yes?\n\nSo what's the deal?  Please explain using words that a clock can understand.\nAonghas, that is true only if the metaphysical things in question have no connection to the physical world.  A god who is said to have done things on Earth can be disproved by establishing that those things did not happen, for example.\n\nHuliendin, just because the truth value of a statement may change does not mean that it does not have one at any given point in time.\n\nDavid, a square is defined as a shape with particular characteristics.  If a shape does not have those characteristics, it is not a square.  It is not possible to discover a square that does not fit the definition of a square.  The same goes for a circle.  And since the two definitions contradict each other, a shape cannot fit both.\n\nRyan, many humans certainly do have ideas about the properties a god would have.  They've written books attributing certain propreties to gods.\nWilliam, you misunderstand the nature of my example.  It doesn't matter whether I have seen one.  The fact is that if one did exist, it would have to fit the definition of a square and it would have to fit the definition of a circle.  That means that, for example, it would have to have exactly one side and exactly four sides.  That is a contradiction, and it is a fundamental assumption of logic that a contradictory statement must be false.\nBloodzwurth, you have trouble proving that because you're being deliberately vague.  It has nothing to do with negativity.  You would have exactly the same difficulty trying to prove that claim to be true as you would trying to prove it to be false.\nI didn't know you spoke clock, CAt.  Anyway I agree with you, but only in respect to a posteriori arguments.\nHuliendin, you are treating my proof as an inductive argument, which it is not.  I am not saying that no squares are also circles because we haven't come across any yet.\n\nLet's put it this way.\n1. If x is a square, then x has straight sides. (That is part of the definition of a square, and so this statement is tautologous and hence must be correct.)\n2. If x is a circle, then x does not have straight sides. (Again, just part of the definition.)\n3. x is both a circle and a square. (Assumed premise.)\n4. x has straight sides (from 1 and 3).\n5. x does not have straight sides (from 2 and 3).\n6. x does and does not have straight sides (from 4 and 5).\n7. x is not both a square and a circle (from 3 and 6, reductio ad absurdum).\n\nSee?  Simple deductive logic.  This proof works for any shape 'x' regardless of whether it has been found or not.  What I have demonstrated is not just that a square circle does not exist, but that a square circle cannot exist.\n",
    "Date": "2010-02-07 23:18:59",
    "Timestamp": "1265584739",
    "Link": "http://answers.yahoo.com/question/?qid=20100207231859AAZVura",
    "Category": {
     "id": "396545163",
     "content": "Religion & Spirituality"
    },
    "UserId": "v2w0u1XAaa",
    "UserNick": "Yellow Alarm Clock",
    "UserPhotoURL": "http://socialprofiles.zenfs.com/images/a3b93240efb619ea3d1b5e2e90844784_48.jpg",
    "NumAnswers": "9",
    "NumComments": "2",
    "ChosenAnswer": "Words a clock can understand huh? Hmmm\n \nOk\n\nTic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc  tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic toc tic t",
    "ChosenAnswererId": "FWZentXQaa",
    "ChosenAnswererNick": "The CAt in the Tin Foil HAt v21",
    "ChosenAnswerTimestamp": "1265585654",
    "ChosenAnswerAwardTimestamp": "1265757240",
    "Answers": {
     "Answer": [
      {
       "Content": "It doesn't matter if you're talking about metaphysical matters (the existence of gods, the afterlife, spirits, whatever), because there's no evidence for or against metaphysical things. Unless you count the lack of evidence as evidence of absence (and some people do, and some people don't).\n\nThe whole point of the matter is that people should just stop worrying about religious/spiritual stuff and just get on with their lives.",
       "Reference": null,
       "Best": null,
       "UserId": "DrMxELRraa",
       "UserNick": "Aonghas M",
       "Date": "2010-02-07 23:22:28",
       "Timestamp": "1265584948"
      },
```

MainActivty:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button getanswer;  

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button getanswer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        getanswer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {       
            EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            String searchTerm = et.getText().toString().trim();         
            Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListView.class);
            in.putExtra("TAG_SEARCH", searchTerm);
            startActivity(in);
        }

        });
    }}
```

This is the way I have tried to parsed the data from the web service:

```
public class ListView extends ListActivity {    


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> questionList;        

     final String TAG_RESULTS = "results";
     final String TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT = "Subject";
     final String TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS = "NumAnswers";
     final String TAG_QUESTION = "question";
     final String TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT = "Content";
     final String TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER = "ChosenAnswer";
     final String TAG_ANSWERS = "answers";
     final String TAG_ANSWER = "answer";    
     final String TAG_ANSWERS_CONTENT = "content";      
     final String TAG_QUERY = "query";

            JSONArray question = null;          

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        //setContentView(R.layout.listview);        




      new LoadAllData().execute();
        }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == 100) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }

    class LoadAllData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            ProgressDialog pDialog; 
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ListView.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Data. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
            if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) pDialog.dismiss();

        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            try {
                Intent in = getIntent();
                String searchTerm = in.getStringExtra("TAG_SEARCH");
                String query = URLEncoder.encode(searchTerm, "utf-8");
                String URL = "http://example.com";
                JSONParsser jParser = new JSONParsser();
                JSONObject json = jParser.readJSONFeed(URL);
                try {
                    //question = json.getJSONArray(TAG_QUESTION);


                    JSONArray questions = json.getJSONObject("all").getJSONArray("questions");

                    for(int i = 0; i < questions.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject question = questions.getJSONObject(i);


                    String Subject = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT);
                    String NumAnswers = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS);
                    String ChosenAnswer = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER);
                    String Content = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT);

                    JSONArray answers = question.getJSONObject(TAG_ANSWERS).getJSONArray(TAG_ANSWER);


                    JSONObject answer = answers.getJSONObject(0);

                    String content = answer.getString(TAG_ANSWERS_CONTENT);

                               HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                               map.put(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT, Subject);
                               map.put(TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS, NumAnswers);

                               questionList.add(map);


                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

                return TAG_QUESTION     ; 



        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_URL) {

                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), questionList,
                        R.layout.listview,
                        new String[] { TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT, TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS }, new int[] {
                        R.id.Subject, R.id.NumAnswers });

                setListAdapter(adapter);

                android.widget.ListView lv = getListView();

                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }   

                });     

        }}

    }
```

Error message:

```
08-11 02:42:52.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4516): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
08-11 02:42:52.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4516): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-11 02:42:52.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4516):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
08-11 02:42:52.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4516):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
08-11 02:42:52.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4516):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
08-11 02:42:52.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4516):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
08-11 02:42:52.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4516):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
08-11 02:42:52.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4516):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
08-11 02:42:52.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4516):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
08-11 02:42:52.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4516):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-11 02:42:52.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4516): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-11 02:42:52.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4516):     at com.theproblemsolver.ListView$LoadAllData.doInBackground(ListView.java:118)
08-11 02:42:52.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4516):     at com.theproblemsolver.ListView$LoadAllData.doInBackground(ListView.java:1)
08-11 02:42:52.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4516):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
08-11 02:42:52.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4516):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
08-11 02:42:52.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4516):     ... 4 more
```

When I read the logcat is gives me an system error that says my results string has no value. The web service is returning data to my jObj string but not the pacific data I have parsed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit 3:** It looks like the JSON response you expect and the actual response have different structures. Try this:

```
JSONArray questions = jObj.getJSONObject("all").getJSONArray("questions");

for(int i = 0; i < questions.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject question = questions.getJSONObject(i);

    String subject = question.getString("Subject");
    String numAnswers = question.getString("NumAnswers");
    String chosenAnswer = question.getString("ChosenAnswer");
    String content = question.getString("Content");
}
```

---

**Edit 2:** With the full JSON you posted, you can see the hierarchy:

```
query -> results -> Question
```

That `Question` node contains all the information you need. This is how you get a reference to it:

```
final String TAG_QUERY = "query";

JSONObject question = jObj.getJSONObject(TAG_QUERY)
    .getJSONObject(TAG_RESULTS)
    .getJSONObject(TAG_QUESTION);
```

From that, you can get the data you want as follows (no need for a loop since there is only one question):

```
String subject = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT);
String numAnswers = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS);
String chosenAnswer = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER);
String content = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT);

JSONArray answers = question.getJSONObject(TAG_ANSWERS).getJSONArray(TAG_ANSWER);

// If you only want the first answer:
JSONObject answer = answers.getJSONObject(0);

String content = answer.getString(TAG_ANSWERS_CONTENT);
```

Try it out and let me know how it goes!

---

**Edit:** Could you copy and paste the whole JSON response? It's impossible to help you if we can't see the structure of the JSON.

---

In the JSON returned from the Yahoo Finance API, the `results` node is not an array, it's an object that contains an array: `Question`, which is the one you are looking for. Try out the following code:

```
final String TAG_RESULTS = "results";
final String TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT = "Subject";
final String TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS = "NumAnswers";
final String TAG_QUESTION = "Question";
final String TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT = "Content";
final String TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER = "ChosenAnswer";
final String TAG_ANSWERS = "Answers";
final String TAG_ANSWER = "Answer";    
final String TAG_ANSWERS_CONTENT = "Content";      

JSONArray questions = jObj.getJSONObject(TAG_RESULTS).getJSONArray(TAG_QUESTION);

for(int i = 0; i < questions.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject question = questions.getJSONObject(i);

    String subject = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT);
    String numAnswers = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS);
    String chosenAnswers= question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER);
    String content = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT);

    JSONObject answers = question.getJSONObject(TAG_ANSWERS);
    JSONObject answer = answers.getJSONObject(TAG_ANSWER);
    String Content = answers.getString(TAG_ANSWERS_CONTENT);
}
```

Comment: i have posted the full JSON data

Comment: the good new is that my app is no longer and just says it has a system error that says query has no value. oh and also I have my app set to return 25 in my url request but I set it to try 1 question but still the same result

Comment: The good news is what? And could you also copy and paste the full error message and your full code if you are able to.

Comment: the good new is that it is no longer crashing and I have updated my question

Comment: `String URL = "http://example.com";` is that supposed to be there? Shouldn't it be the URL to Yahoo Answers' API?

Comment: yes I just put that there for an example. would you like me to put insert the real URL

Comment: No, I was just wondering. Does the line `Log.d("JSON String",json);` print the expected JSON response when you run the application?

Comment: yes it returns data but not the specific data that I have parsed I will print it for you in the question

Comment: Great! I think I know what the problem is now. Please check the updated solution.

Comment: Hmmm... Could you tell me the log output from the updated code in my answer?

Comment: never I have figured it out.  I just needed to change the JSON string from lower case to capital.  So now it is parsing through the data and I know this because I get a Fatal Main AsyncTask #1 caused by this `questionList.add(map);`

Comment: I just posted it in my question

Comment: Comment out these three lines:
`JSONArray answers = question.getJSONObject(TAG_ANSWERS).getJSONArray(TAG_ANSWER);`
`JSONObject answer = answers.getJSONObject(0);`
`String content = answer.getString(TAG_ANSWERS_CONTENT);` and try to run it again.

Comment: You didn't initialize the questionList ArrayList. Do it in `onCreate` **before** the call to `new LoadAllData().execute()`: `questionList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();`

Comment: You're welcome! Could you mark this question solved by clicking the checkmark next to my answer?

Comment: oh yeah there is also one more thing I forgot to ask.  `JSONArray answers = question.getJSONObject(TAG_ANSWERS).getJSONArray(TAG_ANSWER); JSONObject answer = answers.getJSONObject(0); String content = answer.getString(TAG_ANSWERS_CONTENT);` I get an error underneath `content` because there is already a content underneath question and it says I have to rename but I don't think its going to retrieve the answer form the service if I do rename it. So do you think there is a way around this

Comment: Do you think im just going to have retrieve just the chosenAnswer

Comment: I will also have to ask for your assist with a problem I have with my onItemClickListener. Everybody who helped me so far haven't been much help so I was hoping you can take a look at it. If you want to help me here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179595/onitemclicklistener-xml-focus

Answer (score 1):

I recommend taking a look at the gson library for converting from java objects into json and vice versa. http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

You can create classes with all of the relevant fields decorated with the serialized name attribute and then convert to and from json in a single line of code without ever having to manually build your objects.

Answer (score 1):

As already recommended in one of the comments you could do this much more easily with a `GSON` library, you can check this guide I wrote on it's usage and the difference between using this library and using the native object as you currently do right now:

[Parsing JSON Files with Gson and Native Objects](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=746)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should create a class for all the objects you will have to create this makes it easier for you ... and you should try the post of @Raman but you might want to get an array of all the answers not an object just like @Raman said so instead

```
JSONObject answers = question.getJSONObject(TAG_ANSWERS);
```

you might want to make it an array like this to loop through it

```
JSONArray answers = question.getJSONArray(TAG_ANSWERS);
```